# VBA Macro to copy text located in form text box and past text in word document

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word

I have a macro that I use to past text into letters that I write which looks like this:

```
Sub CT1()

Dim myText As String

'Insert text with custom font
myText = "Revisions are necessary"
Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
Selection.Font.Size = 12
Selection.Font.Bold = False
Selection.TypeText (myText)
```

The problem I have is that when I have a long text string, this method gets ugly because I have a very long string that is difficult to read in VBA.

What I want to do is create a form with text boxes to hold my text and I want the macro to get the text from the text box and past it the same way it would using the above macro. This will make it easier for me to edit the text, however I don't know how to execute my vision.

Please help me write this macro.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `Userform`.

You will need to insert a `UserForm` into your Project and then add two `CommandButtons` and a `TextBox`. See below;

[image]

What you can do then is press "F7" to get to the code and place the following there:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'This is the Insert Button
Dim myText As String

'Assigning the Text in the Text box
myText = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text

'Use a With Statement to reduce repetitive typing
With Selection
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 12
    .Font.Bold = False
    .TypeText (myText)
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'This is the Exit Button

'Ends the Process
End
End Sub
```

The Text will be inserted at your current cursor position.

What you then do is Call `UserForm1` from your CT1 Sub:

```
 Sub CT1()
 UserForm1.Show
```